# TFS 2017 Multiple Identities found

Tags: tfs, active-directory

Here is the error I get.  The identities it shows to choose from are identical.

Multiple identities found matching 'XXX\xxx'. Use the unique name to specify one of the following identities:
- xxx_svc_jenkins (unique name: XXX\xxx_svc_jenkins)
- xxx_svc_jenkins (unique name: XXX\xxx_svc_jenkins)

I have tried forcing a resync with Active Directory.  I have checked the identities table in TFS_Configuration which does not show any duplicates.

Active Directory only has one entry for this account.

This was not a problem until an email address was added to this account.  The only difference is that the First Name and Last Name are set to Jenkins and Svc and the Display name is set to xxx_svc_jenkins

In  TFS for the duplicated entry, one entry has an alias assigned which is the same as the account name and the other entry does not have an alias.

We have restarted the TFS Job service which did not fix this issue.

Comment: Hi Sherrill Darby, any update on this thread, have you figured out it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it appears as if there were two users in the [tbl_Identity] TFS DB with the same Display Name.  Running a quick SQL query confirmed this:

```
SELECT     
     [ProviderDisplayName]  
    ,[DisplayName]  
    ,[HasDisplayName]  
    ,[Domain]  
    ,[AccountName]  
    ,[UniqueUserId]  
    ,[LastSync]  
  FROM [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_Identity] where displayname
```

If there are two records, so, the trick is to change the display name on the user and not simply the name.  Once you have changed the display name in AD, you can either wait for TFS to run the AD sync job or force the sync

If there are not two records for same displayname. Please clean the credential cache and browser cookies/history, [TFS server cache](https://mohamedradwan.com/2010/05/15/why-and-how-to-clear-tfs-client-cache/) and then give a try.